# UINavigationController right bar button

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have this code in AppDelegate

```
LoginViewController *loginVC = [[LoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginViewController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *navLogin = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:loginVC];
navLogin.navigationBar.topItem.rightBarButtonItem = myRightBarButton;
self.window.rootViewController = navLogin;
```

I want to set the right bar button for this navigation controller where it won't change the button when pushing new viewcontrollers.

How can achive this ?

Answer (score 1):

you had to set right bar button in each viewcontroller manually . you can use containerview then embed in in your Mainviewcontroller .

then from containerview -> embed segue to new navigationcontroller 
adding view alignment should be like this
view {
     ->button 
     ->containerview
}

like this,
[image]

then each pushed viewcontroller will have the right button automatically

you can set height width of viewcontroller 320 480 i.e all childviewcontroller get fullscreen